Copy files from one Virtual machine to another virtual machine using Azure DevOps pipeline
I want to check the folder in the destination server (VM) is empty or not, if its empty, need to copy the files from the source server(VM) to destination server using azure DevOps pipeline
I am not getting the perfect way to do it

This might help: https://devcodef1.com/news/1104028/copy-files-between-azure-vm-s-with-powershell

You can do like as below:

Set up a self-hosted agent on the source VM to run the pipeline.

Generate the SSH keys on the destination VM. you can reference "Step 1: Create your SSH keys".

On the destination VM, open the Azure DevOps project where you run the pipeline, go to "Project Settings" > "Service connections" to create a new SSH service connection.

Host name: The host name or IP address of the destination VM.

Private Key: The SSH private key generated on the destination VM. You can directly upload the generated private key file (e.g, id_rsa) to this field by clicking "Upload SSH private key file..." option. This option can automatically read the content of the select file and fill the content into this field. If the content filled into this field contains whitespaces or new lines in the end, delete the extra whitespaces or new lines from the end in the field.

Username: A username that to login to the destination VM.

Password/Passphrase: You also can provide the password of the user who can login to the destination VM. Ensure the provided Username and Password are correct and can login to the destination VM.

Service connection name: Give a customized name to the new service connection.



In the pipeline, you can use the CopyFilesOverSSH@0 task to copy files from the agent machine (source VM) to the destination VM.
stages:
- stage: A
  jobs:
  - job: A1
    pool:
      name: {name of the pool where the agent is in}
      demands: Agent.Name -equals {name of the agent}
    steps:
    - task: CopyFilesOverSSH@0
      displayName: 'Copy files to destination VM'
      inputs:
        sshEndpoint: '{name of the SSH service connection}'
        sourceFolder: 'path/to/source/folder/on/agent/VM'
        contents: '**'
        targetFolder: 'path/to/target/folder/on/destination/VM'
        readyTimeout: '20000'




EDIT:
Before the CopyFilesOverSSH@0 task, you can add an SSH@0 task to run the commands/script on the remote destination VM to check whether the destination folder is empty.
steps:
- task: SSH@0
  displayName: 'Detect Destination Folder'
  inputs:
    sshEndpoint: Ubuntu2204SSH
    runOptions: inline
    inline: |
     if [ -z "$(ls -A path/to/destination/folder)" ]; then
       echo "The destination folder is empty!"
     else
       echo "The destination folder is not empty!"
       exit 1
     fi

- task: CopyFilesOverSSH@0
  . . .


When the destination folder is empty, the SSH@0 task will run successfully, then the CopyFilesOverSSH@0 task will run.

When the destination folder is not empty, the SSH@0 task will get filed (exit 1), then the CopyFilesOverSSH@0 task gets skilled.




Thanks for the response, but first I need to check weather the folder is empty in the destination VM, if its empty then only i need to proceed, how can I achieve in the pipeline

@Sushmithashetty, I have updated my above answer with more information (see EDIT). check and try with it.

@Sushmithashetty, As suggested on the latest update above, you can try to use the SSH@0 task to run the commands on the remote destination VM to check whether the destination folder is empty. Then use the CopyFilesOverSSH@0 task to copy the files to the destination folder.
